# Why is the nav bar not changing its background color after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to make my nav bar's background color change from transparent to blue when the nav bar reaches the About section of my page. Based on calls from the console, after scrolling, the `scroll_start` becomes greater than the `aboutOffSetTop`, but the nav bar color does not change. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="titleSection"> 
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul> <li> <a href="index.html">HOME</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="transportation.html">TRANSPORTATION</a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="crafts.html">SHOPS</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="activities.html">EVENTS</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="food.html">FOOD</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="about">
    <p> Text here </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_bar {
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var aboutOffSetTop = $('.about').offset().top;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_start > aboutOffSetTop) {
      $('.nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
    } else {
      $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part:

```
if(scroll_start > aboutOffSetTop) {
            $('.nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
        } else {
            $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```

To this:

```
if(scroll_start > aboutOffSetTop) {
            $('.nav_bar').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
        } else {
            $('.nav_bar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```